# Pixels in PSD not accurate for fonts

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the size of the font translate to exactly?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4035/what-does-the-size-of-the-font-translate-to-exactly)

I'm trying to figure out why my fonts in a PSD are not telling me the accurate pixel height.

I set up a new document at 72pixels/inch, I have rulers and type set to pixels, RGB and 8bit. When I type some text in my font/character panels tell me it's 22px, but when I take the selection tool and select the same height of the font the info. panel is telling me it's only 10pixels tall.

I know the font setting is inaccurate because when I set that pixel height in CSS code for the web it looks enormous in comparison to how it should look from the PSD at 100%.

Can anyone explain what's wrong or what setting's in photoshop I should change so that the font panels accurately represent the true pixel height?

I've searched all over the web but just keep finding stuff on how to switch font point measurements to pixels - that's not my problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Check out the answers to this closely related question: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4035/what-does-the-size-of-the-font-translate-to-exactly?lq=1