# How to change the line height of a font

Tags: fonts, typography

I want to change the "line height" of a font, that is the space between lines when the font is typed. I'd like to increase the space. (I need to use several fonts font in a text app with a fixed (non editable) line spacing).

I'm not very experienced with fonts.  I do have Fontographer, and I tried several things like changing the "base point" but it seems to have no effect.

Comment: Why would you want to mess with font files when you can set the fixed line-height (in pixels) right in your app?

Comment: @Const That is just it, I cannot set the line height in the app. That is why I am asking the question. Thanks.

Comment: What app can you not change line-height in?

Comment: @LaurenIpsum it's a custom mobile entertainment app that my company is developing for a client.

Comment: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/4069/5489 - see if this thread helps you at all. Any glyph in a font is set in an invisible square called an "em-square" or "em-height" by people who answered. Increasing that might increase your leading (line height).

Comment: If you're developing the app, it should be simple to set the leading: [android:lineSpacingExtra](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:lineSpacingExtra), and for iOS: [UITexTView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760924/set-line-height-in-uitextview).

Comment: @Brendan. Thanks, that's exactly that I was looking for. In Fontographer, in font info under dimensions changed UPMSize (em square).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note: This answer is a transliteration of my comment above for the sake of having an answer. MrWolfy noted that changing the UPM size in Fontographer was the equivalent of what I was speculating.*

Any glyph in a font is set in an invisible square called an ["em-square" or "em-height"](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/4069/5489).

Increasing that might increase your leading (line height).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this tiny js script https://github.com/norflin321/font-lh-changer

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/111973)