# How many width and height are for 14 points character?

Tags: font-size

As far as i know :

```
1 point=0.35146cm
14points=4.92044cm.
```

When we set font-size into 14points, how much width and height are for this 14 points character?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the size of the font translate to exactly?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4035/what-does-the-size-of-the-font-translate-to-exactly)

Answer (score 2):

Type doesn't work like that. The height (in mm, cm, etc) of characters set at the same point size, but in different fonts will not be consistent. Also, the width will vary from character to character. An **m** is considerably wider than an **i**, for instance.

There are lots of good resources on the internet that can explain why this is the case so have a search if you  are interested in knowing more.

Here is a good starting point:

> This is a point of confusion since this system comes from the metal
>   type days. Metal type is cast—letter by letter—on individual blocks.
>   All the blocks of a specific size typeface are all the same height.
>   So, the blocks have to be tall enough to contain the caps, the
>   ascenders, and the descenders.

Taken from this page: http://www.peatah.org/measuring.html